# Jquery code comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I need some comments on the code that I "assembled". I want to know if it is efficient because I intend to use it on a live site . I'm not a programmer guy so I used the trial and error method to make this code so don't laugh at me (much), its my first attempt. :)

It's a Hours of operation Input Form.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Ace6h/

If you have any suggestions, please share them. Thanks!

Comment: Might this not be better asked on CodeReview? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps get answers on _what_ you might improve over at CodeReview, then get help here if you can't figure out _how_ to do those things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will post it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. Does not look very optimised.

Also you hav a span where a label belongs and the checkbox IDs are not unique

Here is a start [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/HppgD/)

```
$(this).append('<div id="label">' + day + ': </div>')
        .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromH" name="' + day + 'FromH" class="hour from"></select>')
        .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromM" name="' + day + 'FromM" class="min from"></select>')
        .append('<select id="' + day + 'FromAP" name="' + day + 'FromAP" class="ampm from"></select>')
        .append(' to <select id="' + day + 'ToH" name="' + day + 'ToH" class="hour to"></select>')
        .append('<select id="' + day + 'ToM" name="' + day + 'ToM" class="min to"></select>')
        .append('<select id="' + day + 'ToAP" name="' + day + 'ToAP" class="ampm to"></select>')
        .append(' <input type="checkbox" id="closed_'+day+'" name="closed" value="closed" class="closed" /> <label for="closed_'+day+'">Closed</label>');

});
```

Comment: You still need to change from AM/PM to 24hour or not - now you have 24 hours AND am/pm

Comment: Never mind I will stick to the 24 hours format. Thanks again.